# Finding the real difference between dates in JDK7

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, date-difference

How can I find the difference between two dates in JDK7, **such that the difference can be added back to make the two dates equal?**

I tried to use the solution from a [similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654946/how-do-i-substract-two-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-create-one-duration-object), subtracting one date's milliseconds from the other, but this can result in an incorrect difference between dates.

In this example, I try to make `a` equal to `b` by setting `a = (b-a) + a`

```
private void makeTwoDatesEqual(GregorianCalendar a, GregorianCalendar b, DatatypeFactory datatypeFactory) {
    long b_minus_a = b.getTimeInMillis() - a.getTimeInMillis();
    Duration delta = datatypeFactory.newDuration(b_minus_a);
    delta.addTo(a);
}
```

But the results are unexpected:

**Before**

```
a = "2015-08-29T00:00:00.000Z"
b = "2040-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
delta = "P24Y4M5DT0H0M0.000S" // 2 days longer than it should be.
```

**After**

```
a = "2040-01-03T00:00:00.000Z"
b = "2040-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
delta = "P24Y4M5DT0H0M0.000S"
a.equals(b) = false
```

Joda-Time has this same issue:

```
private void makeTwoDatesEqual(GregorianCalendar a, GregorianCalendar b) {
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime(a);
    DateTime date2 = new DateTime(b);
    Interval interval = new Interval(a.getTimeInMillis(), b.getTimeInMillis());
    Period offsetPeriod = interval.toPeriod();
    date1 = date1.plus(offsetPeriod);
    date1.equals(date2); // false in my example
}
```

**Before**

```
date1 = "2015-08-29T00:00:00.000-05:00"
date2 = "2040-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00"
offsetPeriod = "P24Y4M2DT23H"
date1.equals(date2) = false
```

**After**

```
date1 = "2039-12-31T23:00:00.000-05:00"
date2 = "2040-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00"
offsetPeriod = "P24Y4M2DT23H"
date1.equals(date2) = false
```

Before it's asked, there should be no need to account for daylight savings or leap years because in each example I'm adding the interval back over the exact same time period from which it was derived.

Comment: What you want is impossible for mathematical reasons. Months have different lengths. So if the addition of one month to either 2017-01-28 or to 2017-01-30 yields the same result 2017-02-28 then the way back is necessarily ambivalent.

Comment: That's why the jodatime Interval doesn't work. A Duration, however, should at least be calculable as absolute time which can be added to any date.

Comment: Yes, a duration only in precise units like seconds or minutes (I neglect here leap secs) should do the job. But you also use years and months (imprecise units) in your examples. The class `Period` is not a suitable choice for your requirement.

Comment: Right you are, Meno. I will try with joda.time.Duration instead of Period. I'll answer my question if it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "I tried to use the solution from a similar StackOverflow question, subtracting one date's milliseconds from the other, but this can result in an incorrect difference between dates." Can you give an example?

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff, my first code snippet is an example of this.

Comment: As far as I see, all your code has in common that you try to express the delta in calendar units like year / month / day / hour and so on. I'd leave the difference as linear seconds or similar, then things are MUCH easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Meno explained in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244778/finding-the-real-difference-between-dates-in-jdk7#comment79453749_46244778), date arithmetic is weird, because months and years can have different lenghts. In our ISO calendar, a month can have 28, 29, 30 or 31 days, and a year can have 365 or 366 days.

So, a `Period` like `P24Y4M5D` (24 years, 4 months and 5 days) can represent a totally different number of days, depending on **when** you start counting it.

If I start at `2017-01-01T00:00Z`, for example. If I add 24 years, I get `2041-01-01`, then adding 4 months, I get `2041-05-01`, then adding 5 days I get `2041-05-06`. The total difference is equivalent to **8891** days.

But if I start at `2016-01-01T00:00Z` and add the same period (24 years, 4 months and 5 days): adding 24 years I get `2040-01-01`, then adding for 4 months I get `2040-05-01`, then adding 5 days I get `2040-05-06`. But if I add 8891 days, I get `2040-05-05`.

That's because a month and year don't have fixed lenghts, so the equivalent total in days will always depend on the dates involved (not to mention Daylight Saving Time and leap seconds effects, which also changes the total of hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds).

To not rely on that, you must calculate using the duration in milliseconds (and not in non-fixed-length variables such as years and months). In Joda-Time, you can use the `org.joda.time.Duration` class:

```
public void makeTwoDatesEqual(GregorianCalendar a, GregorianCalendar b) {
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime(a);
    DateTime date2 = new DateTime(b);
    System.out.println("date1=" + date1);
    System.out.println("date2=" + date2);

    Duration duration = new Duration(date1, date2);
    DateTime date3 = date1.plus(duration);
    System.out.println("date3=" + date3);
    System.out.println(date3.equals(date2));
}
```

Assuming that `a` is equivalent to `2015-08-29T00:00:00Z` and `b` is `2040-01-01T00:00:00Z`, this code will output:

> date1=2015-08-29T00:00:00.000Z
>   date2=2040-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
>   date3=2040-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
>   true

---

## ThreeTen Backport

Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and is being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**.

*If you can't (or don't want to) migrate from Joda-Time to the new API, you can ignore this section.*

If you're using **Java 6 or 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

You can use the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class to convert the `GregorianCalendar` to `org.threeten.bp.Instant` and then calculate the difference between them, resulting in a `org.threeten.bp.Duration`:

```
public void makeTwoDatesEqual(GregorianCalendar a, GregorianCalendar b) {
    Instant instantA = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(a);
    Instant instantB = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(b);
    System.out.println(instantA);
    System.out.println(instantB);

    Duration duration = Duration.between(instantA, instantB);

    Instant instantC = instantA.plus(duration);
    System.out.println(instantC);
    System.out.println(instantC.equals(instantB)); // true
}
```

Assuming that `a` is equivalent to `2015-08-29T00:00:00Z` and `b` is `2040-01-01T00:00:00Z`, this code will output:

> 2015-08-29T00:00:00Z
>   2040-01-01T00:00:00Z
>   2040-01-01T00:00:00Z
>   true

Comment: Worth noting here for future readers: in the question, I used java.xml.datatype.Duration whereas I should have been trying with org.joda.time.Duration (although neither can entirely alleviate occasional unexpected results)

Answer (score 7):

### ThreeTen Backport

There are a couple of possibilities using the modern Java date and time API known as JSR-310 or `java.time`. Can you use this with Java 7? Certainly! Get [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and start coding.

### Difference between date-times

**EDIT:** If you want to perceive your `a` and `b` as points in time, in other words, both dates and times of day, you may use either a suitably small time unit for the difference, or the `Duration` class. Both will work the same. Since `Instant`s have nanosecond precision, calculating a difference in nanos will make sure we don’t lose any precision:

```
    Instant a = Instant.parse("2015-08-29T00:00:00.000Z");
    Instant b = Instant.parse("2040-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
    long delta = ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(a, b);
    a = a.plusNanos(delta);
    System.out.println("a = " + a);
    System.out.println("b = " + b);
    System.out.println("delta = " + delta);
    System.out.println("a.equals(b) = " + a.equals(b));
```

This prints

```
a = 2040-01-01T00:00:00Z
b = 2040-01-01T00:00:00Z
delta = 768182400000000000
a.equals(b) = true
```

The `Duration` class is meant for durations in hours, minutes, seconds and fraction of second. You can use it for longer durations, but it doesn’t know about weeks, months or years.

```
    Duration delta = Duration.between(a, b);
    a = a.plus(delta);
```

Otherwise as before. This time the output is

```
a = 2040-01-01T00:00:00Z
b = 2040-01-01T00:00:00Z
delta = PT213384H
a.equals(b) = true
```

So the difference is 213384 hours. Only because the minutes and seconds are 0 in this case, they are not printed, otherwise they would be; `Duration` too has nanosecond precision.

### Difference between dates

Taking your title more literally and noticing that your example dates fall on midnight UTC. If you don’t care about the time of day and only want to count days, months and years, you may use either the `Period` class or simply count days. The `Period` class is for periods of days, months and years and has 1 day precision (that means, cannot be used for hours and smaller units).

```
    LocalDate a = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.AUGUST, 29);
    LocalDate b = LocalDate.of(2040, Month.JANUARY, 1);
    Period delta = Period.between(a, b);
    a = a.plus(delta);
```

The printing goes as before, but now it prints

```
a = 2040-01-01
b = 2040-01-01
delta = P24Y4M3D
a.equals(b) = true
```

Counting days goes just like nanoseconds above, only with days instead:

```
    long delta = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(a, b);
    a = a.plusDays(delta);
```

This time the output contains:

```
delta = 8891
a.equals(b) = true
```

Please note that because months haven’t got the same length, even though 24 years 4 months 3 days seems to equal 8891 days, this will more often not be the exact case. This is explained in more detail in [@Meno Hochschild’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244778/finding-the-real-difference-between-dates-in-jdk7#comment79453749_46244778) and [Hugo’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245454/5772882). So the choice between a `Period` and a number of days will make a difference, and you should choose based on your more exact requirements.

### Combining Period and Duration

It’s a bit funny that Java doesn’t offer a class for a period or duration of years, months, days, hour, minutes and seconds. If you wanted, you might use a `Period` instance for the years, months and days, and then a `Duration` for the hours, minutes and seconds. It’s a little bit complicated but viable.

The [**ThreeTen-extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project includes a `PeriodDuration` class that combines the two. I haven’t got any experience with it myself.

Comment: Upvote for suggestion of ThreeTen Backport. However, question is technically about full date+time (e.g. `2015-08-29T00:00:00.000Z`), so a more on-point answer would include example of using `Instant` and `Duration`.